# CUDA intrinsic functions are undefined according to visual studio's Intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, intellisense

I'm having a compilation error on visual Studio 2017 with the following CUDA (toolkit version 9.0) code:

```
__global__ void increment_atomic(int *g) {
// which thread is this?
int i = blockIdx.x *blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

// each thread to increment consecutive element, wrapping at ARRAY_SIZE
i = i % ARRAY_SIZE;
atomicAdd(& g[i], 1);}
```

the atomicAdd function is not recognized as identifier.
based on suggestion I found i also check the CUDA C/C++ --> Device parameter which is set as hereafter:
[image]

I also try with compute_20, sm_21 but with no result, Some idea about the correct configuration of VS?

Comment: is this an actual build error or just an intellisense issue?

Comment: You are right! It was late yesterday and failed in the loop of trying to make the following error disappear:

Comment: I sent the comment before completing it! I'm saying that the error was effectively only of intellisense. Building the code this morning gives no compilation error and the code runs perfectly. Problem solved ;)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I have two questions. Is there a way to remove such intellisense highlights in a way to gain some hours during night :)? Can you answer to the question in a way to mark it as resolved?

Comment: There are numerous questions about the interplay between CUDA and VS Intellisense if you want to look around for ideas.  It should be easy to get rid of the notations in the Error output pane, by switching from "Build+Intelllisense" to just "Build".  However getting rid of the red underlines may be more difficult, or not really possible in some cases.  The usual advice is to ignore the red underlines emanating from CUDA code unless they actually create a build error.  With regard to this code, the intellisense "error" will not prevent you from building correct code using `atomicAdd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Robert Crovella comment above, it's just intellisense issue that hightlights a non existing error. The compilation and successive run of the code give no errors.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer to your question. Please remember to come back in a few days and accept your answer so that the question falls off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to fix this is to add the intrinsic calls somewhere where intellisense can find them, as shown below.
This has the additional benefit that you get to have popup help regarding the usage and allowed parameters of functions.

**In your main code**

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
    #include "intellisense_cuda_intrinsics.h"
#endif
```

**the file to include**
intellisense_cida_intrinsics.h

```
#pragma once


#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__

#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"


//    Reverse the bit order of a 32 bit unsigned integer. 
__device__ unsigned int __brev(unsigned int  x) {};

//Reverse the bit order of a 64 bit unsigned integer.
__device__ unsigned long long int __brevll(unsigned long long int x) {};


//Return selected bytes from two 32 bit unsigned integers.
__device__ unsigned int __byte_perm(unsigned int  x, unsigned int  y, unsigned int  s) {};


//Return the number of consecutive high - order zero bits in a 32 bit integer.
__device__ int __clz(int  x) {};


//Count the number of consecutive high - order zero bits in a 64 bit integer.
__device__ int __clzll(long long int x) {};


//Find the position of the least significant bit set to 1 in a 32 bit integer.
__device__ int __ffs(int  x) {};


//Find the position of the least significant bit set to 1 in a 64 bit integer.Concatenate hi : lo, shift left by shift & 31 bits, return the most significant 32 bits.
__device__ int __ffsll(long long int x) {};


//Concatenate hi : lo, shift left by shift & 31 bits, return the most significant 32 bits.
__device__ unsigned int __funnelshift_l(unsigned int  lo, unsigned int  hi, unsigned int  shift) {};


//Concatenate hi : lo, shift left by min(shift, 32) bits, return the most significant 32 bits.
__device__ unsigned int __funnelshift_lc(unsigned int  lo, unsigned int  hi, unsigned int  shift) {};


//Concatenate hi : lo, shift right by shift & 31 bits, return the least significant 32 bits.
__device__ unsigned int __funnelshift_r(unsigned int  lo, unsigned int  hi, unsigned int  shift) {};


//Concatenate hi : lo, shift right by min(shift, 32) bits, return the least significant 32 bits.
__device__ unsigned int __funnelshift_rc(unsigned int  lo, unsigned int  hi, unsigned int  shift) {};


//Compute average of signed input arguments, avoiding overflow in the intermediate sum.
__device__ int __hadd(int, int) {};


//Calculate the least significant 32 bits of the product of the least significant 24 bits of two integers.
__device__ int __mul24(int  x, int  y) {};


//Calculate the most significant 64 bits of the product of the two 64 bit integers.
__device__ long long int __mul64hi(long long int x, long long int y) {};


//Calculate the most significant 32 bits of the product of the two 32 bit integers.
__device__ int __mulhi(int  x, int  y) {};


//Count the number of bits that are set to 1 in a 32 bit integer.
__device__ int __popc(unsigned int  x) {};


//Count the number of bits that are set to 1 in a 64 bit integer.
__device__ int __popcll(unsigned long long int x) {};


//Compute rounded average of signed input arguments, avoiding overflow in the intermediate sum.
__device__ int __rhadd(int, int) {};


//Calculate | x − y | +z, the sum of absolute difference.
__device__ unsigned int __sad(int  x, int  y, unsigned int  z) {};


//Compute average of unsigned input arguments, avoiding overflow in the intermediate sum.
__device__ unsigned int __uhadd(unsigned int, unsigned int) {};


//Calculate the least significant 32 bits of the product of the least significant 24 bits of two unsigned integers.
__device__ unsigned int __umul24(unsigned int  x, unsigned int  y) {};


//Calculate the most significant 64 bits of the product of the two 64 unsigned bit integers.
__device__ unsigned long long int __umul64hi(unsigned long long int x, unsigned long long int y) {};


//Calculate the most significant 32 bits of the product of the two 32 bit unsigned integers.
__device__ unsigned int __umulhi(unsigned int  x, unsigned int  y) {};


//Compute rounded average of unsigned input arguments, avoiding overflow in the intermediate sum.
__device__ unsigned int __urhadd(unsigned int, unsigned int) {};


//Calculate | x − y | +z, the sum of absolute difference.
__device__ unsigned int __usad(unsigned int  x, unsigned int  y, unsigned int  z) {};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//atomic functions

int atomicAdd(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicAdd(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicAdd(unsigned long long int* address, unsigned long long int val) {};
float atomicAdd(float* address, float val) {};
double atomicAdd(double* address, double val) {};

typedef int __half2;
typedef short __half;
__half2 atomicAdd(__half2* address, __half2 val) {};
__half atomicAdd(__half* address, __half val) {};

int atomicSub(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicSub(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};

int atomicExch(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicExch(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicExch(unsigned long long int* address, unsigned long long int val) {};
float atomicExch(float* address, float val) {};

int atomicMin(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicMin(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicMin(unsigned long long int* address, unsigned long long int val) {};

int atomicMax(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicMax(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicMax(unsigned long long int* address, unsigned long long int val) {};

unsigned int atomicInc(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};

unsigned int atomicDec(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};

int atomicCAS(int* address, int compare, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicCAS(unsigned int* address, unsigned int compare, unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicCAS(unsigned long long int* address,
    unsigned long long int compare,
    unsigned long long int val) {};
unsigned short int atomicCAS(unsigned short int* address,
    unsigned short int compare,
    unsigned short int val) {};

int atomicAnd(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicAnd(unsigned int* address,
    unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicAnd(unsigned long long int* address,
    unsigned long long int val) {};

int atomicOr(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicOr(unsigned int* address,
    unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicOr(unsigned long long int* address,
    unsigned long long int val) {};

int atomicXor(int* address, int val) {};
unsigned int atomicXor(unsigned int* address, unsigned int val) {};
unsigned long long int atomicXor(unsigned long long int* address, unsigned long long int val) {};

template <typename T>
unsigned int __match_any_sync(unsigned mask, T value) {};
template <typename T>
unsigned int __match_all_sync(unsigned mask, T value, int* pred) {};

template <typename T>
T __shfl_sync(unsigned mask, T var, int srcLane, int width = warpSize) {};
template <typename T>
T __shfl_up_sync(unsigned mask, T var, unsigned int delta, int width = warpSize) {};
template <typename T>
T __shfl_down_sync(unsigned mask, T var, unsigned int delta, int width = warpSize) {};
template <typename T>
T __shfl_xor_sync(unsigned mask, T var, int laneMask, int width = warpSize) {};
#endif
```

Note that I have not included all possible intrinsic functions, but you can just copy-paste those in from the CUDA [c(++) documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) and [math documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html).

Also note that deprecated methods are excluded from the above list by design.