How do I obtain timing in a CUDA c++ kernel?
I finally created a GPU powered low md5-finder, I am so happy! Here is the code, slightly adapted form another implementation:
https://github.com/EnesO226/md5zerofinder/blob/main/kernel.cu
However, when I try to use cudaEvents in the kernel, my visual studio says that cudaEvents are not allowed in a kernel. I want to print the hashrate here, everytime a new hash is found:
__device__ void md5(const uchar* data, const uint size, uint result[4])
{
    uint state[4] = { 0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476 }, i;

    for (i = 0; i + block_size <= size; i += block_size)
    {
        transform(state, data + i);
    }

    uint size_in_bits = size << 3;
    uchar buffer[block_size];

    memcpy(buffer, data + i, size - i);
    memcpy(buffer + size - i, padding, block_size - (size - i));
    memcpy(buffer + block_size - (2 * sizeof(uint)), &size_in_bits, sizeof(uint));

    transform(state, buffer);

    memcpy(result, state, 4 * sizeof(uint));
    if (result[0] == 0 && byteswap(result[1]) < 0x0fffffff) {
        printf("Hash found -------> %08x%08x%08x%08x\n", byteswap(result[0]), byteswap(result[1]), byteswap(result[2]), byteswap(result[3]));
        printf("For data   -------> ");
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%02x", data[j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

    }
}

And the kernel which is actually run is this:
__global__ void test() {
    int thread = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    uchar m[12];
    uint res[4];
    m[0] = (uchar)(thread & 0x000000ff);
    m[1] = (uchar)((thread >> 8) & 0x000000ff);
    m[2] = (uchar)((thread >> 16) & 0x000000ff);
    m[3] = (uchar)((thread >> 24) & 0x000000ff);

    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 0xffffffffffffffff; i++) {
        m[4] = (uchar)(i & 0x000000ff);
        m[5] = (uchar)((i >> 8) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        m[6] = (uchar)((i >> 16) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        m[7] = (uchar)((i >> 24) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        m[8] = (uchar)((i >> 32) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        m[9] = (uchar)((i >> 40) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        m[10] = (uchar)((i >> 48) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        m[11] = (uchar)((i >> 56) & 0x00000000000000ff);
        md5(m, 12, res);
    }
}

int main()
{
    test << <1024, 1024 >> > ();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

How would I go about getting the hashrate here? I asked google (and chatGPT, yes, it is useful sometimes) but I only know how to time the timing when the kernel is already finished, so I would have to set the iterations way lower, but then it does not run indefinitely, you understand? So that is my question; is there a way to get timing in a cuda __device__ or __global__ kernel?
IMPORTANT: my visual studio does not support atomicAdd and clock()

You've answered your own question, use clock() and clock64(). It is only intellisense that does not know about CUDA intrinisics, this can be solved by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289253/cuda-intrinsic-functions-are-undefined-according-to-visual-studios-intellisense/58137486?r=SearchResults&s=37%7C8.8137#58137486

BTW, cuda calls are asynchronous, you need to put cudaDeviceSynchronize() after a global call (i.e. after test<<<x,y>>>()) if you want your CPU code to wait for the call to finish.

@Johan thanks a lot, i didnt find that question before!

cuda::std::chrono might be of interest.
